# Search in database with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a search feature that that will query a database table.

The following form submits the search parameters:

```
<form id="form_searchJobs" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label id="destinationLabel">Destination</label> <input name="destination_search" type="text" id="destination_search"/> <br/>
  <label id="cargoLabel">Cargo</label> <input type="text" name="cargo_search" id="cargo_search"/> <br/>
  <label id="deadlineLabel">Deadline</label> <input type="text" name="deadline_search" id="datepicker"/> <br/>
  <input type="submit" name="search" id="search" class="button3" value="Search"  onClick="showSearchedString()"/>
  <a href="../Jobs.php" id="clearSearch" class="button3">Clear Search</a>
</form>
```

The search feature should allow you to search on each of the textfields individually or all of them simultaneously.

I have the follow database query:

```
if (isset($_POST['destination_search']) || (isset($_POST['cargo_search']) || (isset($_POST['deadline_search'])))) {
  $destination_search = $_POST['destination_search'];
  $cargo_search = $_POST['cargo_search'];
  $deadline_search = $_POST['deadline_search'];
  $newDate = date("y-m-d", strtotime($deadline_search));
  $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE destination LIKE %s OR jobs.cargo LIKE %s OR RSVP_date LIKE %s ORDER BY destination ASC", GetSQLValueString("%" . $destination . "%", "text"),GetSQLValueString("%" . $deadline_search . "%", "text"),GetSQLValueString("%" . $newDate . "%", "text"));
}
else {
$query = "SELECT * FROM jobs ORDER BY destination ASC";
}
```

But this query shows all of the results regardless of the search terms. Something is wrong with my query, but I don't now what it is in order to search from either individual or all variables at the same time?

Comment: You have to modify your query accroding to the Destination,Cargo,Deadline because you are using `OR` in your query you are getting all the results

Comment: But if I use `AND`instead of `OR`the query requires all the fields to be filled in to return a result of a search. So how else can I modify the query according to Destination, Cargo, Deadline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If e.g. your destination_search contains text but your cargo_search and deadline_search not, your outputted query will look something like this:

```sql
$where = [];

if( isset( $_POST['destination_search'] )){
    $where[] = "`destination_search` LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['destination_search'] . "%'";
}

if( isset( $_POST['cargo_search'] )){
    $where[] = "`cargo` LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['cargo_search'] ) . "%'";
}

if( isset( $_POST['deadline_search'] )){
    $newDate = date("y-m-d", strtotime( $_POST['deadline_search'] ));
    $where[] = "`RSVP_date` LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['deadline_search'] ) . "%'";
}

$whereStatement = "";
if( count($where) > 0 ){
    $whereStatement = "WHERE " . implode( " AND ", $where );
}

$query = "
    SELECT    *
    FROM      `jobs`
    " . $whereStatement . "
    ORDER BY `destination` ASC";
```

Does this work better?

Comment: If i use AND instead of OR, then the query fails when all fields are not filled? Or it is not returning anything, because the query needs the two other fields filled in

Comment: I changed my answer, is this better? :)